# Testing p-value for a linear association using Anova result.

Tags: regression, linear-regression, p-value, anova

I have a significance level of 0.05, and two different hypothesises:

- H0 - no relationship between weight and height
- H1 - there is a relationship between weight and height

From my data, my p-value is <.0001, which is less than the significance level, so I accept the alternate hypothesis and reject the null one - which indicates there is a relationship.

However, my coefficient value is 0.00577, which is close to 0, so wouldn't that contradict the idea of there being a relationship?

I am so confused - please help me out.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're executing ANOVA? The hypothesis test for one way ANOVA has an $F$ test statistic, not a $t$ test statistic. This looks like to output of a simple linear regression.

Comment: *$H_0$ - no relationship* What kind of hypothesis is that?

Comment: Sorry, @MatthewHolder. I have updated it now.

Comment: @callculus - I have made the edits; relationship between height and weight.

Comment: If the points of the weight (or height?) lie close around the function of the height (or weight?) then there is no problem. Also note that  $0.00577$ is an absolute value. The attribute "small" is relative.

Comment: Okay, so the coefficient for the Height variable is 0.00577. And, as my P-Value is less than 0.05, does this show a relationship between height and weight?

Comment: Does the coefficient not contradict my hypothesis, as it is close to 0?

Comment: *Height variable is 0.00577* So the function is $W=0.00577\cdot H+2.03953$? As I said: f the points lie close around the function then there is no problem.

Comment: ANOVA tests the hypothesis that two or more population means are equal, not whether there exists a *linear* relationship between two quantitative variables. That being said, I don't think ANOVA is an appropriate test here. Also, you can change the units of measurement for weight and/or height to make the coefficient even smaller. For example, if you change your measurement of height from feet to inches, your coefficient of 0.00577 would become much smaller, but this won't change the determination that there exists a linear relationship between height and weight.

Comment: @callculus - Right, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewHolder - Okay, I see what you mean there, but how would I use the ANOVA result to see if there is a linear association?

Comment: Why don't you use perform the hypothesis test $H_0:\beta_1=0$ VS $H_a:\beta_1\neq 0$ using the test-statistic $t=\frac{\hat{\beta_1}}{\sqrt{\frac{MSE}{\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-\bar{x})^2}}}$ which has $n-2$ degrees of freedom. Here, $\hat{\beta_1}$ is the observed slope of your least$-$squares regression line from your sample and $MSE=\frac{1}{n-2}\sum_{j=1}^n(y_j-\hat{y}_j)^2$. You can obtain the $p-$value of this hypothesis test from the first table that you showed me.

Comment: You could also perform the hypothesis test $H_0:\rho=0$ VS $H_a:\rho \neq 0$ by using the test statsitic $t=\frac{r\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$ which has $n-2$ degrees of freedom. Here, $r$ is the sample correlatrion coefficient which has formula $$r=\frac{\sum(x-\bar{x})(y-\bar{y})}{\sqrt{\sum(x-\bar{x})^2}\sqrt{\sum(y-\bar{y})^2}}$$

Comment: @MatthewHolder - Thank you very much for the help.